# A navbar and 3 columns with scrollable content inside with bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a new layout with bootstrap but, there is a problem. I want a fix layout that only content inside columns can scroll not the whole page. My code works if there is no content inside but, when I add text inside of any of the column the whole page will scroll not the content inside the column.

```css
.page-container {
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
 .page-container .page-container.nav-global {
     padding: 20px 20px;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: 999;
}
 .page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left {
     display: inline-block;
}
 .page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left a {
     color: #ccc;
     margin-right: 15px;
}
 .page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left > i {
     color: #ccc;
}
 .page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-right {
     float: right;
}
 .page-container .page-content {
     border: none;
     flex-grow: 1;
     background-color: #eee;
}
 .page-container .page-content .filter {
     align-items: center;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}
 .page-container .page-content .result {
     border: none;
}
 .page-container .page-content .map {
     border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class='page-container'>
    <nav class='nav-global'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-6'>
                <div class='nav-left'>
                    <a href='#'>
                        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
                    </a> 
                    logo
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-6'>
                <div class='nav-right'>
                    <i class="fas fa-lock fa-xs"></i> Join Now
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class='page-content container-fluid'>
        <div class='row h-100'>
            <div class='col-3 filter'>
                scrol    
            </div>
            <div class='col-3 result'>
                CONTENT
            </div>
            <div class='col-6 map'>
                MPA
            </div>                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: explain in brief, I don't understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question description, it seems that you're looking for a fix layout that only content inside columns can scroll not the whole page... so set a fixed height to the 3 divs and added `overflow-y:scroll`... check the **code snippet** below:

```css
.page-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page-container .nav-global {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left {
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left a {
  color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-left>i {
  color: #ccc;
}

.page-container .page-container.nav-global .nav-right {
  float: right;
}

.page-container .page-content {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.page-container .page-content .filter,
.page-container .page-content .result,
.page-container .page-content .map {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.page-container .page-content .filter {
  align-items: center;
}

.page-container .page-content .result {
  border: none;
}

.page-container .page-content .map {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='page-container'>
  <nav class='nav-global'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-6'>
        <div class='nav-left'>
          <a href='#'>
            <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
          </a>
          logo
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-6'>
        <div class='nav-right'>
          <i class="fas fa-lock fa-xs"></i> Join Now
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class='page-content container-fluid'>
    <div class='row h-100'>
      <div class='col-3 filter'>
        scrol <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temporLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum incididunt ut labore et d
      </div>
      <div class='col-3 result'>
        CONTENT <br/> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborumveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      </div>
      <div class='col-6 map'>
        MPA <br/> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehe nderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deseruntLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```